# Vanity URL Creation

Tags: php

I've been looking for an answer but I just can't find one. I'm not looking for a way for a user on my site to be able to quickly get to their page, and quite frankly, the same question keeps popping up, "How to Create a Facebook Profile URL" or, "How to use ".htaccess". I'm just looking for a simple bit of PHP that can create basic vanity URL's so I can quickly access different pages on my site and make it look more neat.

Comment: The reason this ".htaccess" keeps popping up is because you need to do some server-side configuration to create such "vanity URLs" -- you can't do it in straight PHP. You can use `.htaccess` to point a request to a PHP file, and *then* you can handle the rest in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in .htaccess to send all requests to index.php (this is called a front controller)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Then put this in your index.php

```
<?php
  // get the request
  $request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  // split the path by '/'  
  $params     = split("/", $request);
```

You now can request a page like: `http://foo.com/one/two/three`

Your `$params` variable will now look like:

```
$params = array('', 'one', 'two', 'three');
```

You can now use those parameters to call functions or redirect to pages or whatever you want.

This is a **very** simplified example but it should give you the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support vanity URLs at all, you need to configure your webserver to use them.

.htdocs are configuration files for apache, however, your case may be:

1. Apache hasn't been configured to process these.
2. Your server isn't apache httpd.