# Using mod_rewrite to remove index.php completely

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for a way to remove any file name that is index.php from the URL. The main reason I want to try and do this is because I have directories with "index.php" in them. So instead of getting...
**http://localhost/members/index/**
I am hoping to achieve something more like...
**http://localhost/members/**
The code below is currently what I have in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

I really appreciate the help and any suggestions! Thank you so much and God bless!

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270692/vanity-url-creation/11270883#11270883

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, but unfortunately this scenario didn't work for me. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is 'remove' index.php from your URLs then you just need to ensure Apache knows that index.php can be used as a directory index.

`DirectoryIndex index.php`

You can put that in your Apache config, VirtualHost or .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*index.php.*
```

That's it ;)