# Friendly URLs using rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url

```
http://mysite.com/profile?id=78
```

I wanted to changed it to be like this

```
http://mysite.com/78/
```

How would I do that?

I have this code in my htaccess, but it seems it's not working.

```
RewriteRule ^id/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile?id=$1
```

Kindly guide me on this one.

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270883/210547

Comment: possible duplicate of [mod_rewrite: rewrite to "pretty URL"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245831/mod-rewrite-rewrite-to-pretty-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you should use the `RewriteBase` directive

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^u/(!(profile.php))$ u/$1/ [R=301,L]
# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^u/(!(profile.php))/$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite `http://mysite.com/u/john/` to `http://mysite.com/profile?name=john`.

**Edit** this is the new answer

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^u/(!(profile.php))$ u/$1/ [R=301,L]
# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^u/(!(profile.php))/$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ u/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But i'm doing it the other way around, like: From http://mysite.com/profile?name=john to 

http://mysite.com/john/

Comment: @ElsonSolano This is what you need. When we say `rewrite`, it means that the browser sees `http://mysite.com/u/john/` but looks in `http://mysite.com/profile?name=john`. The user still sees the clean URL though.

Comment: @ElsonSolano see if this is what you want

Comment: @ElsonSolano If your site serves other function as well, removing `u/` will be unwise because it could simply blocks other functions as well

Comment: @AlvinWong: It's okay, my site does not block other functions. It is really intended to have a format of like this: http://mysite.com/john

Comment: @ElsonSolano then you simply remove the `u/`, doesn't that work?

Comment: @AlvinWong: Yes it totally works! :) I hope there won't be a lot of bugs when doing this one.

Again, thanks! :)

Comment: Wow. Don't try this at home kids…

Comment: @AlvinWong: Do you have an idea how to fix this one? I have a username that has a dot on it john.doe, but it seems it redirects me to a 404.shtml page. RewriteRule ^u/([\.a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ profile.php?name=$1 [L] , I made that change "\." but it seems it's not working. But if a username has no ".", example johndoe, it works fine.

Comment: @AlvinWong: The page is not redirecting properly. Seems like there's an infinite loop happening.

Comment: @AlvinWong: check my answer, I did it that way and looks like it's working.

Answer (score 1):

What you have appears correct. However, the request will likely get processed again.

You could avoid that by adding the `[L]` flag and ensuring you map to the exact file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^name/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L]
```

**Note:** I've also made the trailing slash optional. And I explicitly turned the `RewriteEngine On`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /profile?name=$1 [L]
```

I used this to generate it: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: This is a very open rule. It's better to make them more specific.

Comment: Agreed. But the OP wants this way right? Hopefully he should be giving only the names.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^(v)$ /$1/
# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ profile.php?id=$1
# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ %1?
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this one in a mulitple way? like, I also want to implement this one on my category.php, I'm trying to copy that code below and just replace the profile.php into category.php but what happens is that the profile.php redirects me to the category.php. You have any idea?