# How to create Friendly Url with htaccess from php queries

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm stuck and I don't know how to create friendly urls rewriting and redirecting my php urls. I would actually like to convert this url structure:

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog/post.php?id=myid&year=2018&titleurl=my-perfect-title
```

into this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/blog/my-perfect-title
```

And of course all the users and search engine have to see only this last one.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  There are already many questions (and answers) on this topic.  Just a short list: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002203/seo-friendly-url), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303949/friendly-urls-using-rewrite-in-htaccess)

Comment: You have more than 1 dynamic value, how do you expect the others to be sent?

Comment: Could use `/blog/BQmUDDr/my-perfect-title`, if you [hash](https://hashids.org/) them ids into one param: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KRRZoL - Then serverside decode them back into the params, or put up with `/blog/123/2018/my-perfect-title`

Comment: All the questions found are quite different and include other parameters... I'd like to have a short link rewrited without year and id but only with the seo title. Is this possible?

Comment: If your page doesn't load from this `www.mywebsite.com/blog/post.php?titleurl=my-perfect-title`, then you're not going to be able to load it from this `www.mywebsite.com/blog/my-perfect-title` without making changes  to the code the decides what content to load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create friendly URL in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812571/how-to-create-friendly-url-in-php)